# How to get function arguments type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types, arguments

For example I have `foo(...)`:

```py
def foo(arg1: str, arg2: int, ...):
    ...
```

And I want to get this:

```py
{'arg1': str, 'arg2': int, ...}
```

Please share with me if anyone knows anything about the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accessed via the `__annotations__` attribute of a function object for Python versions >= 3.0:

```
type_annotation_dict = foo.__annotations__
```

Which should directly result in a dictionary mapping the parameter names to their type annotations:

```
{'arg1': str, 'arg2': int}
```

See also [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#accessing-function-annotations).

Additionally, the `typing` standard library module has a function `get_type_hints` which provides some additional functionality. See [the Python docs on this function](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. 

Comment: Glad I could help! If this or another answer addressed your question, you could choose one as the currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).